# Agregar clase CSS en collection_select por medio html_options en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Comunidad, presento un problema con el colletion en Rails ya que no se como colocar una clase de CSS dentro del colletion. Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

Comment: ... y la forma que lo haces es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collection_select` acepta un *hash* como último argumento donde puedes especificar los atributos html, entre ellos `class`; por ejemplo:

```
<%= collection_select(:project, :name, @projects, :id, :name, { prompt: "Seleciona proyecto"}, { class: "mi-clase"} ) %>
```